# CCK Node Reference options not showing "this post can't be referenced."

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, users

I have a CCK field of node reference. As user 1 I can set the node ference field to a node. I will see something like *Node Title[nid:123]*. When I go in as another user I see *[nid:123]*. When I go to save the node I get the message:

> Field: this post can't be referenced.

I can't work out why I am getting this. Any ideas?

Comment: my guess would be that the user is either not allowed to see that node or is not allowed to reference it (for example because only nodes you're the athor of can be referenced).

Comment: check your permissions for this field using admin account..

Comment: @Berdir - I didn't realise that it was an issue whether or not the user can see the referenced node: are you thinking of the user not having _access content_ permission, or the user being denied by content access modules? (Or both/something else!)

Comment: Yes, either a content access limitation or a limitation of the field configuration, see Andy's answer. Since it can't even display the title, my guess would be content access.

Comment: @Berdir if you create an answer will mark as correct. The access to the node type did not allow users to view it.

Comment: @Jeff Created the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from restrictions placed directly on the field configuration (see Andy's answer), nodereference also checks if a user can access referenced (or to be referenced) nodes and only allows to reference those that the user is allowed to view according to the content access rules.

Make sure your content access modules, if you're using any, allow access to those nodes for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Nodereference checks that the node is valid before allowing it to save. This check is either a 'standard' check that sees if the node is of the appropriate content type (if you configured the nodereference under the *Content types that can be referenced* checkboxes); or if you're using Views it can be a 'views' check (if you configured the nodereference under *Advanced - Nodes that can be referenced (View)*) that sees if the specified node is in the output of the view.